# How can I get a pixel's color at a specific coordinate of an Image/Bitmap given a base64 string in React-Native (Expo managed)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, image-manipulation

I'm creating an Expo project using React Native and want to find the color of a pixel at x and y coordinates. The image will be the picture taken from the [Expo camera module](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) represented in base64.

```
<Camera ref={cR} style={{flex: 1}} type={type} onCameraReady={() => {
if (cR){ 
    cR.current.takePictureAsync({base64: true}).then((data) => {
        const source = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}`;
        //Is there a way to achieve something like below (note that Image is just a made-up function)?
        /* -----------------------------------------------
            var img = Image(source);
            console.log(img.getPixel(x, y)); // Should output an rgb object/array or hex code
             
        */ -----------------------------------------------
            
    });
}
}}>
```

Is there a simple way to do something as shown in the comment?

**Note:** I have already tried using 3rd party libraries, such as

- [React Native Pixel Color](https://github.com/spacesuitdiver/react-native-pixel-color)
- [React Native Get Pixel](https://github.com/bvic23/react-native-get-pixel)
- [React Native Get Pixel Color](https://github.com/dudyn5ky1/react-native-get-pixel-color)

, but they use native modules in react native, and don't work with an Expo managed project.

## Edit

I'm now using a GLView from expo-gl and using Expo-2d-context for a "canvas" type approach:

```js
<GLView style={{flex: 1}} onContextCreate={(gl) => {
    var x = 50;
    var y = 50;
    var ctx = new Expo2DContext(gl);
    // how to define imag as an image that can be passed into drawImage?
    ctx.drawImage(imag, 0, 0, imag.props.width, imag.props.height);
    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
    console.log(imageData);
}}/>
```

Now my only problem is drawing an image to [Expo2dCanvas](https://github.com/expo/expo-2d-context) using drawImage. I don't know what to pass for the first argument (which is the asset).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528299/get-pixel-color-of-base64-png-using-javascript

This may help

Comment: See if [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380265/does-react-native-support-base64-encoded-images) has useful Answers for you...

Comment: JoelBonetR - That solution is nice for react web apps, but mine is an expo-managed react native app.

VS.One - I'm already using a base64 string as the source of an image.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this library [get-pixels](https://github.com/scijs/get-pixels). from what I saw it works with both JPEG and PNG images and it does not use native modules. Hope it works for you.

here is the code:

```
const getPixels = require("get-pixels");
const util = require("util");
const string =
  "data:image/png;base64, --- data ---";

const base64toBuffer = Buffer.from(string.substring(22), "base64");

async function getPixelAt(x, y, buffer, format) {
  const getPixelsPromisse = util.promisify(getPixels);

  pixels = await getPixelsPromisse(buffer, `image/${format}`);
  const pixelAt = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    pixelAt.push(pixels.get(x, y, i));
  }

  return pixelAt;
}

getPixelAt(0, 0, base64toBuffer, "png").then((pixel) => console.log(pixel));
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: path is not defined

Comment: remember to add get-pixels with `npm install get-pixels` or `yarn add get-pixels`, and also to make the imports on the first and second line, here is an example of why this error occurs [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801984/referenceerror-path-is-not-defined-express)

Comment: Nothing is happening when I run the function using the code you provided

Comment: @JosephBalnt I had the same issue, I had to do some node patching like `npm i path` or `npm i buffer`, which got rid of those issues.  Now I'm stuck at `ReferenceError: Image is not defined` - @LucasAndrade, did you run into any such issues?  I guess `get-pixels` uses an HTML Image element, which doesn't exist in react native?