# Angular 12 warning Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, webpack, angular12, angular-builder

I'm getting these warnings after ng build (Angular 12):

`./node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:35289:13-34 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

`./node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:35301:13-100 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

I'm using @angular-builders/custom-webpack to extract the moment.js from the initial bundle.

**If I disabled the @angular-builders/custom-webpack, then everything goes well and the warnings disappear.**

Also, the warnings disappeared if I add the following within custom-webpack.config.js:

```js
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
    /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)__ivy_ngcc__(\\|\/)fesm2015/,
    path.join(__dirname, './src'),
    {}
),
```

So kindly, what causing these warnings exactly? and is there any other solution to handle it without adding the plugin to the webpack config like above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following feedback from the Angular dev team:

> This comes from code in the deprecated [SystemJsNgModuleLoader](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.2.x/packages/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.ts) and is
> normally suppressed when [using the CLI builders](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/12.2.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs/common.ts), which also uses
> ContextReplacementPlugin. I don't think there is an alternative to
> suppress them, other than to not suppress them and ignore the
> warnings.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43092#issuecomment-895848535

So I ended up using the mentioned CLI builders code as the following within custom-webpack.config.js:

```js
// Always replace the context for the System.import in angular/core to prevent warnings.
new ContextReplacementPlugin(
    /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)/,
    path.join(__dirname, '$_lazy_route_resources'),
    {}
),
```

Comment: Was getting: `[error] ReferenceError: path is not defined`. Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58802078/134120

Answer (score 1):

When using a custom `ContextReplacementPlugin` in Angular 12, [take care about this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack/v/7.4.3#merging-plugins-configuration):

> If in your custom configuration you specify a plugin that is already
> added by Angular CLI then by default the two instances will be merged.

I use the ContextReplacementPlugin to [exclude moment.js locales](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6137#issuecomment-419822929). After upgrading to Angular 12, all locales were removed, because it's config was merged with [$_lazy_route_resources](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/12.2.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs/common.ts#L494). I solved it by setting `replaceDuplicatePlugins` to `true`.